# How to upgrade Angular 2 version in Cordova app

Tags: cordova, angular, monaca

Now I'm trying to update Angular2 in my Cordova(Monaca) app, and then I tested this way.

```
rm -rf node_modules dist tmp
npm install --save-dev angular-cli@latest
```

But I think this cause errors of differences among Angular2, Cordova and other frameworks such as OnsenUI.

Does anyone know any other way?

Answer (score 0):

you just updated `angular-cli`, you should update the angular version in `package.json` too. You can check [This](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update) update guide of angular-cli.

Comment: Thank you for answering, and I've done trying the same way and succeeded it!